# Counting the number of binary sequences satisfying certain properties

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Let $a^n\in\left\{0,1\right\}^n$ be a given binary sequence of length $n$. Also, let $f_i:\left\{0,1\right\}^i\to\left\{0,1\right\}$, for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ be a sequence of "majority mappings", that is, for $1\leq i\leq n$ and $b^n\in\left\{0,1\right\}^n$,
$$
f_i(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_i) = \mathrm{sgn}\left(\frac{1}{i}\sum_{j=1}^ib_j-\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$
where $\mathrm{sgn}(x) = 1$ if $x\geq0$, and zero otherwise. Finally, let $$f^n(b^n) = (f_1(b_1),f_2(b_1,b_2),\ldots, f_n(b^n)).$$ 
For $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb{N}$, I wonder how one can calculate the number of sequences $b^n\in\left\{0,1\right\}^n$ satisfying the following two properties:

1) The weight of $b^n$ is $d_1$, i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^nb_i=d_1$, and

2) The Hamming distance of $a^n$ from $f^n(b^n)$ is $d_2$, i.e., $d_H(a^n,f^n(b^n)) = d_2$, where for two binary sequences $a^n,b^n\in\left\{0,1\right\}^n$, $d_H(a^n,b^n) = \sum_{i=1}^n|a_i-b_i|$.

Equivalently, what can be said about (even asymptotic/exponential behavior for large $n$, or upper bounds)
$$
S_n(d_1,d_2,a^n) = \sum_{b^n\in\left\{0,1\right\}^n}\mathbb{1}\left\{d_H(a^n,f^n(b^n)) = d_2,\;\sum_{i=1}^nb_i=d_1\right\}.
$$

For example, if we had only the first constraint then the number of such sequences is ${n}\choose{d_1}$ which exponentially behave like $\exp(nH(d_1/n))$ where $H(\cdot)$ is the Binary entropy.